# How can I route a URL request to get data, plus run a function to change the CSS in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a link that is used to load data, and then I want the CSS styling to change.  I want both the data to be loaded and the CSS change to happen from one click event.

```
<section ng-controller="OffrdHeadCntrl">
<section id="menuOff" ng-class="{true: 'OpenMenu', false: 'ZeroWide'}[MenuStatus]">
    <b>Menu</b><br>
    <nav>
       <ul id='OffrdCat'>
          <li><a href="#Antiques">Antiques</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Appliances">Appliances</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
     .... More HTML in another section here.
</section>
```

This is the routeProvider:

```
var ysshApp = angular.module('ysshApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ysshControllers',
  'firebase'
]);
  // 'ysshServices'

ysshApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/Antiques', {
        templateUrl: 'Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.html',
        controller: 'CommonController',
        customInput: 'zeg0yv7nxle6a5sr2xl-ezs'
      }).
      when('/Appliances', {
        templateUrl: 'Client_Pages/Offered_Menu.html',
        controller: 'CommonController',
        customInput: 'zh86tu488b8g6maw9wrfk'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo:'/Tab_Home_1' });

  }]);
```

When the user clicks 'Antiques', a bunch of data loads.  The link triggers the URL to change, and that causes the $routeProvider to use a controller that then loads the data.  I also have a function that changes the CSS styling:

This is the controller that loads the data:

```
var ysshControllers = angular.module('ysshControllers', []);

ysshControllers.controller('CommonController',
    function($scope, $http, $route) {
        $scope.dbKey = $route.current.customInput;
        $scope.urlToDb = 'https://' + $scope.dbKey + '.firebaseio.com/.json';
        $http.get($scope.urlToDb).success(function(data) {
            var values = [];
            for (var name in data) {
            values.push(data[name]);
            }
            $scope.UsedItems = values;
            });
            // Initially order by date and time
            $scope.orderProp = 'Time';
            }     
        );
```

There is the function/controller?  that changes the CSS:  (I stripped some stuff out)

```
 function OffrdHeadCntrl($scope) {
    $scope.OpenCloseMenu = function() {
            if ($scope.MenuStatus === true) {
                $scope.OutputStatus = 'MuchWide';}
            else
                {$scope.OutputStatus = 'FullWideVal';}
 };
}
```

I can get either the CSS to change, or the data to load, but not both.  I've tried putting the `ng-click="OpenCloseMenu()"` in all kinds of places, but either the routeProvider will work, or the CSS change will work, but not both.

I've tried adding lines of code to the Common Controller, but that doesn't work.  Can I add an event that runs after the data is done loading?  I've seen examples that create a service that relates multiple controllers, but it's for binding data, not running a button click event.

I'm trying to change the CSS in order to hide the menu part the page before the data is loaded.  I can use the `Resolve` object property to cause something to be resolved first, before the data is loaded.  That would work, but I'm having trouble configuring the controller so it is available.  I can get `Resolve` to work, but I can't get the function to fire.  If I add this to the routeProvider, an alert msg will pop up, then once I click OK, the data loads.

```
            resolve: {
                // Run code in resolve first
                whatever: function() {
                alert("it ran");
                }
            }
```

This will work for me if I can get the function I need to run, but I haven't figured that out yet.

I successfully got a `$routeChangeSuccess` to run, but it runs BEFORE the data is loaded.

```
ysshControllers.controller('OffrdCatChg', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
        alert("it ran the success?");
    });
});
```

So, I don't think that is going to help me.  I created a new controller, and put the name of the controller into an HTML tag in that page.  It runs when the route changes, but it runs before the data is loaded.  That would be okay, but some of my other code runs afterwards, and sets the CSS back to the original.  There must be a way to test for a particular controller having been run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.  First of all, I think I had my controller defined wrong.  I had a function defined, and it was working, but I don't think it was set up right.  I had a function written like this:

```
function CntrlMyCSS($scope) {
    $scope.OpenCloseMenu = function() {
            if ($scope.MenuStatus === true) {
                $scope.OutputStatus = 'MuchWide';}
            else
                {$scope.OutputStatus = 'FullWideVal';}
 };
}
```

I didn't have it tied to a module, or defined as a controller.  This is the new change.

**ysshControllers.controller('HideShowInOffered',**

```
ysshControllers.controller('HideShowInOffered',
 function CntrlMyCSS($scope) {
    $scope.OpenCloseMenu = function() {
            if ($scope.MenuStatus === true) {
                $scope.OutputStatus = 'MuchWide';}
            else
                {$scope.OutputStatus = 'FullWideVal';}
 };
}
);
```

So, I guess that even though I added

`ng-controller="CntrlMyCSS"`

to a HTML tag, and it worked, it wasn't really a controller?  idk.  I was using the name of a function as the controller.  I know that defining it as a controller seemed to make the stuff inside that controller available to my other controller.  I still don't really understand, but basically I just added a line at the top of the function to tie it to the module, and define it as a controller, and change the HTML tag to the name of the controller instead of the name of the function.

The other thing that helped was being able to debug the code by setting break points, stepping through lines, and looking at assigned values.  If it wasn't for that, I'd probably still be going down roads to nowhere.

The fix was basically just tweaking what I had set up.  I tried `$routeChangeSuccess`, but by stepping through the code, I saw that it was firing before the data loaded.  That didn't work for me, because the controller was setting default CSS values for when the page originally loads.  So it would change the CSS, and then set it back to original.  Which happens so fast, I wouldn't have known that without the debugger.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
    alert("it ran the success?");
});
```

Trying to get a fix through the routeProvider didn't seem to be of any use either.  It was basically an issue of the code being available to be called, and learning the timing the program flow through debugging.

The lesson to the story?  Take the time to make sure you have a way to step through your code, and determine what the program flow is.  There are probably infinite numbers of bad guesses, and maybe only one solution.  The odds are against you unless you can debug.

This is the controller that loads the data, then formats the data, then changes the CSS to close the menu.

```
ysshControllers.controller('CommonController',
    function($scope, $http, $route) {
        $scope.dbKey = $route.current.customInput;
        $scope.urlToDb = 'https://' + $scope.dbKey + '.firebaseio.com/.json';
        $http.get($scope.urlToDb).success(function(data) {
            var values = [];
            for (var name in data) {
            values.push(data[name]);
            }
            $scope.UsedItems = values;
            });
            // Initially order by date and time
            $scope.orderProp = 'Time';
            $scope.MenuStatus = false;
            $scope.OutputStatus = 'FullWideVal';
            }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data loaded is accompanied by url change, so link may be directly visited, not only from the clicking previous ones, so you should put data-loading in the first place.

As for the CSS changing, it's a state reflection thing, closely related to url changing(If I understand your description right), so you should listen to url change event, in something like a rootController( aside from ng-view), such as:

```
    $scope.$on '$routeChangeSuccess', (e, current, previous) ->
        //getting url segments, and updates css as it should be
    return
```

The logic for me is:

```
click the link ---> router change ---> new controller(data load)
                    |
                    |
                    |--------->routeChangeSuccess event ---> update the css
```

Comment: Thank you.  That program flow seems like it will work.  I'll research the '$routeChangeSuccess' event.